# Convert list element from String to int

Tags: python, list, csv, sorting

I have stored data from csv file to a list, and that list has all string elements.
I wanted to sort that list using first column or first element(which is string). I was thinking of converting that string into integer and then use list.sort() function.
This is my code, but it does not work properly because it takes first element as string instead of integer.one of the rows in csv looks like
228,,Sieur de Duplessis (Le),24.2,47,,,"Sharp, lactic" 
I want to convert first column element(228) into integer and then do sorting. how can do it?

```
sample = open('file.csv', 'r')

data = csv.reader(sample, delimiter=',')

list_cheese = []  # empty list declaration
next(data)  # skip first line in csv file, column names

for row in sample:
    list_cheese.append(row)

list_cheese.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(0))

# print sorted list items
for elem in list_cheese:
    print elem
```

file.csv has more than 2000 rows, but I am sharing first three to give some content of csv file.

```
CheeseId,CheeseNameEn,CheeseNameFr,ManufacturerNameEn,ManufacturerNameFr,ManufacturerProvCode,ManufacturingTypeEn,ManufacturingTypeFr,WebSiteEn,WebSiteFr,FatContentPercent,MoisturePercent,ParticularitiesEn,ParticularitiesFr,FlavourEn,FlavourFr,CharacteristicsEn,CharacteristicsFr,RipeningEn,RipeningFr,Organic,CategoryTypeEn,CategoryTypeFr,MilkTypeEn,MilkTypeFr,MilkTreatmentTypeEn,MilkTreatmentTypeFr,RindTypeEn,RindTypeFr,LastUpdateDate

228,,Sieur de Duplessis (Le),,Fromages la faim de loup,NB,Farmstead,Fermière,,,24.2,47,,,"Sharp, lactic",Marquée et lactée,Uncooked,Pâte non cuite,9 Months,9 mois,0,Firm Cheese,Pâte ferme,Ewe,Brebis,Raw Milk,Lait cru,Washed Rind,Croûte lavée,2016-02-03

242,,Tomme Le Champ Doré,,Fromages la faim de loup,NB,Farmstead,Fermière,,,24.2,47.9,,,"Sharp, lactic, lightly caramelized","Marquée, lactée et légèrement caramélisée",Uncooked,Pâte non cuite,,,0,Semi-soft Cheese,Pâte demi-ferme,Cow,Vache,Raw Milk,Lait cru,Washed Rind,Croûte lavée,2016-02-03

301,Provolone Sette Fette (Tre-Stelle),Provolone Sette Fette (Tre-Stelle),Tre Stelle (Arla Foods),,ON,Industrial,Industrielle,htt
```

Comment: file.csv has rows with mixed information, like first column as ID(which is stored as String), second column name of the cheese and so on.. I wanted to stored ID from string to int and then sort the list on the basis of ID

Comment: Should `for row in sample:` actually be `for row in data:`?

Comment: Instead of `csv`, highly recommend you use `pandas`. This should be approx. 4-5 lines, tops.

Comment: @JeromeMontino You should strive to use inbuilt functionality when you can. If you are working with `csv` just use the `csv` module. Don't import a third party module.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse There might be some merit in your opinion but it is not the best solution. He is obviously working on some CSV _data_ manipulation, which `pandas` does better than the `csv` module, which is simply a CSV read-and-write module.

Comment: @JeromeMontino They are reading, sorting, and printing. None if which are made faster via pandas....

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Never said anything about faster, just that it's simpler. My point is basically to hedge against eventual manipulation. If he was simply sorting and printing, then maybe your point stands. But I'm thinking that's not the end of what he's gonna do, hence the recommendation of `pandas`. No need to turn this into the usual argument of `it's always better to use builtin functionality`.

Comment: Use [context managers](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html) when dealing with files!

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the loop and convert the current element type from String to int as mentioned below, am sure you can also use lambda to do this as well.

```
 for element in my_list:
...     print(element)
...     element_int = int(element)

here, if element itself contains a list then, 
you can further access its elements as element[0] and then convert it to int.
```

Comment: but this would  convert the whole row, which included name of the cheese and other columns, into integer, I am looking to convert just first column(ID) into integer.

Answer (score 0):

This should perform a numerical sort based on the first field of each row:

```py
sample = open('file.csv', 'r')

data = csv.reader(sample, delimiter=',')

list_cheese = list(data)[1:]

list_cheese.sort(key=lambda fields: int(fields[0]))

# print sorted list items
for elem in list_cheese:
    print elem
```

Comment: it worked perfec!! I just added reverse in sort() method
list_cheese.sort(key=lambda fields: int(fields[0]), reverse=True).   thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full example, reading, sorting, and writing it back to an output file.
I use the built-in `csv` module for easy reading and writing.

```
import csv
with open('input.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
    rows = list(csv.DictReader(csv_file))
    headers = rows[0] if rows else [] # Use the first row as the headers
    rows.sort(key=lambda x: int(x['CheeseId'])) # Sort by the CheeseId as an int


with open('output.csv', mode='w') as cheese_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(cheese_file, headers)
    dict_writer.writeheader() # Write the headers
    dict_writer.writerows(rows) # Write the rows
```

[See it in action.](https://repl.it/repls/HeavenlyVillainousTitle)